# Checkbox state control - best option? (javascript/jquery, database or other)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm trying to find the best way to implement a solution and I want to hear your opinion on this.

I have a form (rails - simpleform) with several fields. Some of these fields have a checkbox associated. The use for the checkbox is simple: if the user wants to leave the field blank (the data might be missing) he needs to check the checkbox, this is to make sure that he left the field in blank for purpose.

Right now I'm controling the checkboxes with javascript and jquery validations. And for the fields I use on the model the following validation

```
validates :field, acceptance: true, :unless => :field?
```

This is working except if the user forgets to input some data, and rails throws back some error (for example: "field must be accepted"), then the pages refreshes and the checkbox state is lost.

To control this on the "edit" or "update" action I have a script running on document load that checks if the content of the field is empty, if it is, then it's a sign that the checkbox should be checked...

Besides this not being very efficient, it doesn't work on the "new" or "create" action, when an error occurs and the page gets refreshed.

So I'm looking for better solutions... Should I use something like jquery.cookie and store the checkbox state on a cookie? Should I add all checkboxes to the database and control the state that way? (i don't like the idea of having gigantic tables to control everything on the database...) Should I pass the state as parameters on the form?

What's your thoughts on the best solution to accomplish this?

--- Update ---

Here's the controller code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @sample.save
    format.html { redirect_to @sample, notice: 'Sample was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @sample, status: :created, location: @sample }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @sample.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

And on the view:

```
<% if @sample.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation" class="field_with_errors">
    <h3>Não foi possível gravar o registo. Erro(s) encontrado(s): <%= pluralize(@sample.errors.count, "erro") %></h3>
    <ul>
    <% @sample.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Form

```
<%= simple_form_for @sample, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<!-- Error messages while saving-->
<% if @sample.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation" class="field_with_errors">
    <h3>Não foi possível gravar o registo. Erro(s) encontrado(s): <%= pluralize(@sample.errors.count, "erro") %></h3>
    <ul>
    <% @sample.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<br>
<!-- end of error messages -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Detalhes da Informação</legend>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :pcris, "PCR Anterior?", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.select :pcris, NAOPREENCHIDO, :include_blank => true %>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <div class="resultpcr control-group">
        <%#= f.label :resultFirstTest, "Res. PCR Anterior", :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%#= f.select :resultFirstTest, RESULTADO, :include_blank => true, :id => 'result_first_test' %>
      </div>
      </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :colheitaPCR, "Colheita de PCR", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.select :colheitaPCR, COLHEITA_PCR, :include_blank => true %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :dateOfSample, "Data de Colheita", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.text_field :dateOfSample, :class => 'date_field' %><input type="checkbox" name="dtc" id="dtc_nao_preenchido">nao preenchido<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :horaColheita, "Hora de Colheita", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.text_field :horaColheita, :class => 'time_field' %><input type="checkbox" name="hc" id="hc_nao_preenchido">nao preenchido<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :dateSampleSent, "Data de Envio da U.S.", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.text_field :dateSampleSent, :class => 'date_field' %><input type="checkbox" name="dtss" id="dtss_nao_preenchido">nao preenchido<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dateSampleReceived control-group">
                    <%= f.label :dateSampleReceived, "Data de Entrada no Lab", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.text_field :dateSampleReceived, :class => 'date_field' %><input type="checkbox" name="dtsr" id="dtsr_nao_preenchido">nao preenchido<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :sampleReceivedBy, "Amostra recebida por", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.text_field :sampleReceivedBy, :class => 'text_field' %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :motherPMTCT, "PTV da Mãe", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.select :motherPMTCT, MOTHER_PMTCT, :include_blank => true %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :infantPMTCT, "PTV da Criança", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.select :infantPMTCT, INFANT_PMTCT, :include_blank => true %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :semanasPMTCT, "Quantas Semanas", :class => 'control-label' %>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <%= f.select :semanasPMTCT, SEMANAS_PMTCT, :include_blank => true %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-eid">
  <i class="fa fa-check"> Gravar FSR</i>
</button>
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-times"> Cancelar</i>'.html_safe,
            samples_path, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sounds like something you're doing in the controller is working against the Rails grain. If you `respond_with @resource` in your controller's `else`, then you should see a page reload with the errors rendered inline, and the information (other than passwords) remembered.

Comment: It does look right. Is the other, non-password information for @sample still there? Also, could you put your form up there? And finally, could you try removing the `unless: :field` section of your validations?

Comment: Yes, the remaining fields are still there. only the checkboxes loose their status.

Comment: I also tried without the unless: :field but the behavior is the same